# JAVA :: copy List object1 to list object2 where both the objects have same variables

Tags: java, hibernate, collections

I am trying to copy all the objects in the List with object1 to a list with object2:

Below is my code snip:

```
List<EmployeeAmManegmentModel> am = employee.amEmployeeDeatails();
List<EmployeeRmManegmentModel> rm = employee.rmEmployeeDeatails();  
List<EmployeeGenericModel> GM = new ArrayList<>();
```

Here I am trying to copy `am` and `rm` to `GM`. All the 3 models have same parameters:

EmployeeAmManegmentModel:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PROFILE_AM")
public class EmployeeAmManegmentModel {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "AM_ID")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "CONTACT_NUMBER")
    private Long contactNumber;

    @Column(name = "EMAIL_ID")
    private String emailId;

    @Column(name = "STATUS")
    private Long status;

    @Column(name = "EMPLOYEE_TYPE")
    public  String employeeType = "AM"; ..... getters and setters
```

EmployeeRmManegmentModel

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "RM_ID")
private Long id;

@Column(name = "NAME")
private String name;

@Column(name = "CONTACT_NUMBER")
private Long contactNumber;

@Column(name = "EMAIL_ID")
private String emailId;

@Column(name = "STATUS")
private Long status;

@Column(name = "EMPLOYEE_TYPE")
public  String employeeType = "RM";
```

EmployeeGenericModel

```
private Long id;
private String name;
private Long contactNumber;
private String emailId;
private Long status;
private String employeeType;
```

Is there any way to copy the result from one list of different object type to another?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not entirely sure how this is related to Hibernate. You have Hibernate Entities, but copying attributes from an object of one class to an object of another class does not affect Hibernate.

There is no entirely automatic way to do this. However, there are libraries for mapping objects of different classes onto each other.

One such library with very comprehensive features for mapping is [Dozer](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 0):

If EmployeeAMMenegement and EMplyeeRMManagement model is same class with some several more method you can use extend EmployeeGenericModel from that both class.

But you can do this by creating mapper from AM, or RM class.

```
public class EmployeeAmManegmentModel {
  public EmployeeAmMenegementModel(EmployeeGenericModel egm){
    this.id = egm.id;
    this.name = egm.name;
    //dst
  }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I right understood your task, you could do something as like:

```
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    List<EmployeeGenericModel> GM = am.stream()
                    .map(x -> gson.fromJson(gson.toJson(x), EmployeeGenericModel.class))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());

    GM.addAll(rm.stream()
                    .map(x -> gson.fromJson(gson.toJson(x), EmployeeGenericModel.class))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two BeanUtils.copyProperties(parameter1, parameter2) in Java.

One is 
org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtils.copyProperties(Object dest, Object orig)

Another is
org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.copyProperties(Object source, Object target)